# How to read data from a socket on html page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a HTML page (written in JSP but there aren't any JSP elements as yet), now there is a long process which runs on the server and it writes its various completion stages on a socket. I need to read that socket and show the timestamp of stage completion on my HTML page.
If anyone can suggest how to achieve this or if there is any way to catch socket events like this??

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. To get you started I've searched too much on net and there is comet programming, socket.io, etc. actually I'm not too good in HTML, Ajax...I'm a Java guy so not too much into website development and stuff...

Comment: *"i have an html page (written in jsp.."* Do you have a shift key?  That should be "I have an HTML page (written in JSP.."  Please use upper case where appropriate to help the reader.  Further 1) Spell words like "you" & "good" properly.  This is not a text message.  2) Given this is a Q&A site, it pays to always ask a question.  What is your question?

Comment: You can use WebSocket to achieve this. But not all browsers (based on version) support WebSockets yet. http://www.websocket.org/ Example : http://ajeeshwrites.blogspot.in/2011/02/peek-at-websockets.html

Comment: I'll take care of proper formatting in future for sure. And I've edited the question so it properly states "what my question exactly is?"

Comment: yeah I read Websockets as well but its HTML5... :(

Answer (score 0):

How to achieve this without using any JSP tag?
I do think about using Javascript, but this script should use JSP to get data from Server too.